# What is the expected number of balls that fall into the first bin when m balls are distributed into n bins uniformly at random?

Tags: balls-in-bins

I have a problem from the "discrete mathematics and its applications" textbook.

What is the expected number of balls that fall into the first bin when m balls are distributed into n bins uniformly at random?

This is my current attempt:
Let X be a random variable that represents the number of balls in the first bin.
Let E(X) be the expected number of balls in the first bin.
Then, E(X) = p(X=1)1 + p(X=2)2 + ... + p(X=m)m

How do I figure out p(X=r), and then find their sum?

Comment: The expected value will be the same for all $m$ bins. if you add them up they will sum to $n$

Comment: See [Linearity of Expectation](https://brilliant.org/wiki/linearity-of-expectation/),
which includes a proof that the formula applies even when the events are not 
independent of each other.  Then, what is the probability that the very first ball goes into bin-1?  Alternatively, the analysis inherent in the comment of @WW1 also solves the problem.

Comment: Could you please give a detailed answer?